# Does Raku have a global interpreter lock (GIL)?

Tags: raku

The Wikipedia article *[Global interpreter lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)* indicates that Raku has a global interpreter lock.

This contradicts [Curtis Poe's response](https://www.quora.com/Are-any-companies-planning-to-use-Perl-6/answer/Curtis-Poe) to *[Are any companies planning to use Perl 6?](https://www.quora.com/Are-any-companies-planning-to-use-Perl-6)*.

I suspect that the Wikipedia article is wrong - but maybe it is more complicated than that. Can somebody explain?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the wikipedia page. Perhaps the edit is related to this line of thinking from [a year ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/2w3asu/suspending_rakudo_support_for_parrot/cooc1ae):

> > > parrot has no GIL, perl6 on moarvm has.
> >  What makes you think MoarVM has a GIL?
> It has no real GIL, just locks on all data writes. I used "GIL" just as a non-technical description of the locking problem. Which is essentially the same as a GIL. ... parrot scales linearily with the number of CPUs on concurrent tasks, moarvm not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With some googling I've found some additional evidence that Perl 6 indeed has no GIL:

As the creator of Perl himself stated in [an interview](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2882300/perl/perl-creator-larry-wall-rethought-version-6-due-this-year.html):

> [...] For developers who are already sophisticated, they'll see that most of the problems endemic to the currently available dynamic languages are solved in Perl 6. We understand lexical and dynamic scoping. We detect most typos at compile time. **We don't have a global interpreter lock.**

*Source: [Perl creator Larry Wall: Rethought version 6 due this year](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2882300/perl/perl-creator-larry-wall-rethought-version-6-due-this-year.html)*

Some more evidence:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10640765
- https://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/3goq1a/not_having_gil_truly_multithreading/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/337h4c/should_i_also_learn_perl6_knowing_ruby_and_python/

I don't know why, but the addition of Perl 6 to the Wikipedia article was done [two weeks ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Global_interpreter_lock&action=history) and maybe it needs to be reverted.

Comment: Thanks Agis.  I have edited the Wikipedia to revert it.